# Remove & Clear Selected Attribute Filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my product lister tempalte, I've got some filters `ul.current-filters li` which show currently selected product attributes. On click, the filter buttons should disapear `ul.current-filters li`. On clicking the "clear filter" button `.clear-current-filters`, all filters should be removed. If there is only one filter remaining, it should be removed, along with the clear filter button.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="product-filter-buttons-container">
        <!-- Product Filter list -->
        <ul class="current-filters">
        <div class="clear-current-filters">Clear Filters<a href="#">x</a></div>
        <!-- Product Filter Attributes -->
        <li>Nike<a href="#">x</a></li>
        <li>Adidas<a href="#">x</a></li>
        <li>£90 - £100<a href="#">x</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery** - This is what I currently have, unfortunately it does not work as intended. How do I reference the delgated element? It seems as though $(this) references the initial `ul.current-filters li`

```
$(".product-filter-buttons-container").on("click", "ul.current-filters li", function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this);

        if ((a.length) > 0) {
            a.hide();
        } else {
            a.hide();
            $(".clear-current-filters").hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be the delegated element?

Comment: That is invalid HTML, `<ul>` elements don't have `<div>` inside directly!

Comment: I was trying to get a length on the clicked elment i.e `ul.current-filters li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('.current-filters > li > a').click(function(e){
   var $this = $(this),
       clearAll = $this.parent('li').hasClass('clear-current-filters'),
       lastOne = $('.current-filters > li ').length == 2;

    if(clearAll || lastOne){
        $this.closest('ul').empty();
    }else{
        $this.parent().remove();
    }
});
```

For this:

```
<div class="product-filter-buttons-container">
    <!-- Product Filter list -->
    <ul class="current-filters">
        <li class="clear-current-filters">
            Clear Filters<a href="#">x</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            Nike<a href="#">x</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            Adidas<a href="#">x</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            £90 - £100<a href="#">x</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See it work [**in this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/px5Lw3Lk/2/)

Comment: Just missing the removal of the `clear-current-filters` when there are no remaining filter buttons. Currently if you remove all the individual filter buttons, the `clear-current-filters` remains, and has to be removed.

Comment: @Liondedan I updated the answer and linked fiddle to address that.